# Assembly in dosbox clear screen

Tags: assembly, x86-16, dos, dosbox

I wanna clear screen on the display but then when I try it's always either the screen is cleared but then it will be zoomed in or the screen is cleared but my cursor is gone and all my code details are gone

```
.model small
.stack 64
.data
    welcome     db  "Welcome to Penang Travel Bus System!: $"
    msg1        db  10,13, "Pick up destinations : $"
    msg2        db  10,13, "Drop up destinations : $"
    pickupTitle db  10,13, "---- Your Pickup Destination ---- $"
    dropoffTitle    db  10,13, "---- Your Drop-off Destination ---- $"
    destination1    db  10,13, "1. Spice Arena Bayan Lepas $"
    destination2    db  10,13, "2. Ayer Itam Bus Terminal $"
    destination3    db  10,13, "3. Komtar Sentral Georgetown $"
    destination4    db  10,13, "4. Balik Pulau Bus Terminal $"
    destination5    db  10,13, "5. Gurney Plaza Pulau Tikus $"
    destination6    db  10,13, "6. Vantage Point Bus Stop Tanjung Tokong $"
    pickupPrompt    db  10,13,10,13, "Enter the number of your pickup destination (1-6): $"
    dropoffPrompt   db  10,13,10,13, "Enter the number of your drop-off destination (1-6): $"
    pickupChoice    db  ?  
    dropoffChoice   db  ?
    pickupchosen    db  10,13, "You selected pickup destination: $"
    dropoffchosen   db  10,13,  "You selected drop-off destination: $"
    invalid_pickup  db  10,13, "Invalid pickup destination. Please select from (1-6): $"
    invalid_dropoff db  10,13, "Invalid drop-off destination. Please select from(1-6): $"
    invalid_destination db 10,13,"Your drop-off destination cannot be same as your pickup destination. Please select other destination: $"
    invalid_quantity db 10,13, "Invalid quantity. Minimum number of tickets is 0 and maximum is 9. Please select from (1-9): $"
    invalid_feature db 10,13, "Invalid feature. Enter from (1-4) or (0) for no features. $"
    quantityPrompt  db  10,13,10,13, "Enter the quantity of tickets (1-9): $"
    ticketQuantity  db ?
    features    db  10,13,10,13, "Would you like any of these extra features? $"
    snacks      db  10,13, "1. Snacks of your choice: (Twisties / Super Ring / Cheezels / Chips) - RM7.00 $"
    beverages   db  10,13, "2. Cold beverages (100Plus / Cola / 7UP / Sprite) - RM7.00 $"
    entertainment   db  10,13, "3. TV Entertainment (Smart TV) - RM10.00 $"
    wifi        db  10,13, "4. Onboard WiFi - RM8.00 $"
    featuresPrompt db 10,13, "Enter the features you want (1-4) Press (0) if no : $"
    featuresChoice db 0
    featuremessage  db  10,10, "Feature added. Would you like any more features? $"
    chosenfeatures db 10,13, "Feature chosen: $"


;==========================================================================

.code
    main    proc    far

    mov ax , @data
    mov ds , ax;

    call clear_screen

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , welcome
    int 21h
    
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , pickupTitle
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , msg1
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination1
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination2
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination3
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination4
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination5
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination6
    int 21h
    
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , pickupPrompt
    int 21h


    ;Read user input for pickup choice
get_pickup:
    mov ah , 01h            ; Please prepare I want to read a char
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h            ; Change it to integer
    
    cmp al , 1
    jl invalidpickup
    cmp al , 6
    jg invalidpickup
    
    mov pickupChoice, al
    jmp get_dropoff

invalidpickup:              ; Display an invalid pickup message if user doesn't enter from 1 to 6
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , invalid_pickup
    int 21h
    jmp get_pickup

;Dropoff menu

get_dropoff:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx, dropoffTitle    ; Display the title
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx, destination1    ; Display drop-off 1
    int 21h
        
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination2   ; Display drop-off 2
    int 21h

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx , destination3   ; Display drop-off 3
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination4   ; Display drop-off 4
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination5   ; Display drop-off 5
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination6   ; Display drop-off 6
    int 21h
        
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , dropoffPrompt
    int 21h

    mov ah , 01h            ; Please prepare I want to read a char
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h            ; Change it to integer

    cmp al , 1              ; If user doesn't enter (1-6) it shows an error message
    jl invaliddropoff
    cmp al , 6
    jg invaliddropoff

    mov dropoffChoice , al  ; Protect the input

;We also need to check if the dropoff choice is the same as pickup
;Need to load to register to only use cmp

    mov al , pickupChoice
    cmp al , dropoffChoice
    je invaliddestination

    mov pickupChoice , al   ; Move it back to the variable

    jmp destination

invaliddropoff:             ; Error message and loop back to get user input
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , invalid_dropoff
    int 21h
    jmp get_dropoff

invaliddestination:         ; Error message if user enters same destination for pickup and dropoff
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , invalid_destination
    int 21h
    jmp get_dropoff

destination:
        call clear_screen       ; Clear the screen and then display the chosen destinations
        int 10h

        mov ah , 09h
        lea dx , pickupchosen
        int 21h


        mov dl , pickupChoice
        add dl , 30h
        mov ah , 02h
        int 21h

        mov ah , 09h
        lea dx , dropoffchosen
        int 21h

        mov dl , dropoffChoice
        add dl , 30h
        mov ah , 02h
        int 21h

; Prompt for the quantity of tickets

        mov al , 0          ; Clear the al register just in case

get_ticketquantity:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , quantityPrompt
    int 21h

; Read user input for quantity

    mov ah , 01h
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h            ; Change to integer
    

; Check if the quantity is valid (between 1 and 9)

    cmp al , 1
    jl invalidquantity
    cmp al , 9
    jg invalidquantity

    mov ticketQuantity, al      ; Protect the value
    jmp extrafeatures

    invalidquantity:

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx, invalid_quantity    ; Display error message for invalid quantity
    int 21h

    jmp get_ticketquantity      ; Repeat the loop to get a valid quantity

extrafeatures:
;Code to display any extra features the user may input
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , features
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , snacks
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , beverages
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , entertainment
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , wifi
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuresprompt
    int 21h

    mov ah , 01h
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h                    ; Protect the input

    cmp al , 0
    je displayfeatures              ; Jump to displayfeatures if user enters 0
    cmp al , 1
    je addsnacks
    cmp al , 2
    je addbeverages
    cmp al , 3
    je addentertainment
    cmp al , 4
    je addwifi

    jmp invalidfeature

    addsnacks:
    or featuresChoice, 1            ; If user chooses snacks, the corresponding bit is set (bit 1)
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
    int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeatures

    addbeverages:
    or featuresChoice, 2            ; If user chooses beverages, the corresponding bit is set (bit 2)
    call clear_screen                       ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
    int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeatures

    addentertainment:
    or featuresChoice, 4            ; If user chooses entertainment, the corresponding bit is set (bit 3)
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
    int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeatures

    addwifi:
    or featuresChoice, 8            ; If user chooses wifi, the corresponding bit is set (bit 4)
    call clear_screen                       ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
    int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeatures

    invalidfeature:
    cmp al , 1
    jne validfeature                ; If true , jump to valid feature option that 
                                    ; repeats without showing invalid feature message
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
    int 10h

    mov ah , 09h                    ; If it didn't jump , this error message will appear
    lea dx , invalid_feature
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeatures

    validfeature:                   ; If the jump occured it will just loop back as normal
    jmp extrafeatures

displayfeatures:
    jmp finaldisplay                ; Jump to final display

finaldisplay:
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and summarize the user order
    int 10h 
        
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , pickupchosen
    int 21h

    mov dl , pickupChoice
    add dl , 30h
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , dropoffchosen
    int 21h

    mov dl , dropoffChoice
    add dl , 30h
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h

    mov ah  , 09h
    lea dx , quantityPrompt
    int 21h

    mov dl , ticketQuantity
    add dl , 30h
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , chosenfeatures
    int 21h

    ; Check snacks
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 1    ; Check the least significant bit (snacks)
    cmp al , 1
    je snacks_chosen
    jmp beverages_check

snacks_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , snacks
    int 21h
    jmp beverages_check

beverages_check:
    ; Check beverages (bit 1)
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 2    ; Check bit 1 (beverages)
    cmp al , 2
    je beverages_chosen
    jmp entertainment_check

beverages_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , beverages
    int 21h
    jmp entertainment_check

entertainment_check:
    ; Check entertainment (bit 2)
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 4    ; Check bit 2 (entertainment)
    cmp al , 4
    je entertainment_chosen
    jmp wifi_check

entertainment_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , entertainment
    int 21h
    jmp wifi_check

wifi_check:
    ; Check WiFi (bit 3)
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 8    ; Check bit 3 (WiFi)
    cmp al , 8
    je wifi_chosen
    jmp final

wifi_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , wifi
    int 21h
    jmp final

final:
    mov ax , 4c00h
    int 21h


    main    endp
    clear_screen:
    mov ax,0b800h
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,0
    mov di,ax
    mov ax,160
    mov si,ax
    cld
    mov cx,24*80
    rep movsw
end main
```

I expected clear screen and then moving on to the next display

Comment: Screen can be also cleared as a side effect of re-switching the videomode:  `MOV AX,0003h ; INT 10h`.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in last part. This will copy bytes from `ds:si` to `es:di`, starting from `ds:160` and go up the memory because direction flag is cleared `cld`. Some random character and colors appear on the screen.

```
clear_screen:
    mov ax,0b800h
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,0
    mov di,ax
    mov ax,160
    mov si,ax
    cld
    mov cx,24*80
    rep movsw

    ret      ; add return
```

If You want to use above code, hmm, maybe add `clearBuffer dw 80*24 dup(0)` and then copy bytes from `clearBuffer` to `es:di (B800h)`. But this will increase program size.

```
clear_screen:
    mov ax,0b800h
    mov es,ax
    mov ax,0
    mov di,ax
   
    mov si,offset clearBuffer
    cld
    mov cx,24*80
    rep movsw

    ret      ; add return
```

I think better way is to copy immediate value to vram.

```
clear_screen:
        mov ax,0b800h
        mov es,ax           ; es = b800h
        mov ax,0700h        ; ah = character's attribute, al = character
        mov di,0            ; di = 0    
        cld             
        mov cx,25*80
        rep stosw           ; copy from ax to es:di
    
        ret
```

and `REMOVE int 10h after every call to clear_screen`. This should eliminate big letters on the screen.

---

### `UPDATE`

Well I dig into the code...

1. I added `set_cursor_0_0` to set cursor at 0,0 coords. Reset after each user input. To keep things clean and nice on the screen.
2. Background is blue, Foreground is white.
3. Back to text mode, reset attributes to normal.
4. And below is full code

```
.model small
.stack 64

.data
     newline     db 13,10,'$'       ; Added
    welcome     db  "Welcome to Penang Travel Bus System!: $"
    msg1        db  10,13, "Pick up destinations : $"
    msg2        db  10,13, "Drop up destinations : $"
    pickupTitle db  10,13, "---- Your Pickup Destination ---- $"
    dropoffTitle    db  10,13, "---- Your Drop-off Destination ---- $"
    destination1    db  10,13, "1. Spice Arena Bayan Lepas $"
    destination2    db  10,13, "2. Ayer Itam Bus Terminal $"
    destination3    db  10,13, "3. Komtar Sentral Georgetown $"
    destination4    db  10,13, "4. Balik Pulau Bus Terminal $"
    destination5    db  10,13, "5. Gurney Plaza Pulau Tikus $"
    destination6    db  10,13, "6. Vantage Point Bus Stop Tanjung Tokong $"
    pickupPrompt    db  10,13,10,13, "Enter the number of your pickup destination (1-6): $"
    dropoffPrompt   db  10,13,10,13, "Enter the number of your drop-off destination (1-6): $"
    pickupChoice    db  ?  
    dropoffChoice   db  ?
    pickupchosen    db  10,13, "You selected pickup destination: $"
    dropoffchosen   db  10,13,  "You selected drop-off destination: $"
    invalid_pickup  db  10,13, "Invalid pickup destination. Please select from (1-6): $"
    invalid_dropoff db  10,13, "Invalid drop-off destination. Please select from(1-6): $"
    invalid_destination db 10,13,"Your drop-off destination cannot be same as your pickup destination. Please select other destination: $"
    invalid_quantity db 10,13, "Invalid quantity. Minimum number of tickets is 0 and maximum is 9. Please select from (1-9): $"
    invalid_feature db 10,13, "Invalid feature. Enter from (1-4) or (0) for no features. $"
    quantityPrompt  db  10,13,10,13, "Enter the quantity of tickets (1-9): $"
    ticketQuantity  db ?
    features    db  10,13,10,13, "Would you like any of these extra features? $"
    snacks      db  10,13, "1. Snacks of your choice: (Twisties / Super Ring / Cheezels / Chips) - RM7.00 $"
    beverages   db  10,13, "2. Cold beverages (100Plus / Cola / 7UP / Sprite) - RM7.00 $"
    entertainment   db  10,13, "3. TV Entertainment (Smart TV) - RM10.00 $"
    wifi        db  10,13, "4. Onboard WiFi - RM8.00 $"
    featuresPrompt db 10,13, "Enter the features you want (1-4) Press (0) if no : $"
    featuresChoice db 0
    featuremessage  db  10,10, "Feature added. Would you like any more features? $"
    chosenfeatures db 10,13, "Feature chosen: $"

;==========================================================================

.code
    mov ax,0003h                ; Added
    int 10h                     ; Added
   
    main proc far

    mov ax , @data
    mov ds , ax 
    
   call clear_screen            ; Added
    call set_cursor_0_0         ; Added

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , welcome
    int 21h
    
    mov ah , 09h                ; Added
    lea dx , newline            ; Added
    int 21h                 ; Added
;==============================================================
    
Pickup:                         ; Added 
                                ; this starts Pickup part
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , pickupTitle
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , msg1
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination1
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination2
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination3
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination4
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination5
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination6
    int 21h
    
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , pickupPrompt
    int 21h

    ;Read user input for pickup choice
get_pickup:
    mov ah , 01h            ; Please prepare I want to read a char
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h            ; Change it to integer
    
    cmp al , 1
    jl invalidpickup
    cmp al , 6
    jg invalidpickup
    
    mov pickupChoice, al
    jmp Dropoff             ; Changed
                                ; Pickup and Dropoff labels
                                ; marks start of next phase

invalidpickup:              ; Display an invalid pickup message if user doesn't enter from 1 to 6
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , invalid_pickup
    int 21h
    jmp get_pickup

;Dropoff menu

Dropoff:                        ; Added
   call clear_screen            ; Added
    call set_cursor_0_0         ; Added
    
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx, dropoffTitle    ; Display the title
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx, destination1    ; Display drop-off 1
    int 21h
        
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination2   ; Display drop-off 2
    int 21h

    mov ah, 09h
    lea dx , destination3   ; Display drop-off 3
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination4   ; Display drop-off 4
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination5   ; Display drop-off 5
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , destination6   ; Display drop-off 6
    int 21h
        
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , dropoffPrompt
    int 21h
    
get_dropoff:                    ; Added
                                ; labels get_pickup and get_dropoff
                                ; want input from user
    mov ah , 01h            ; Please prepare I want to read a char
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h            ; Change it to integer

    cmp al , 1              ; If user doesn't enter (1-6) it shows an error message
    jl invaliddropoff
    cmp al , 6
    jg invaliddropoff

    mov dropoffChoice , al  ; Protect the input

;We also need to check if the dropoff choice is the same as pickup
;Need to load to register to only use cmp

    mov al , pickupChoice
    cmp al , dropoffChoice
    je invaliddestination
                              ; Removed
                              ; Value pickupChoice is in memory already
                        ; no need to save this again                              
   ; mov pickupChoice , al   ; Move it back to the variable

    jmp destination

invaliddropoff:             ; Error message and loop back to get user input

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , invalid_dropoff
    int 21h
    jmp get_dropoff

invaliddestination:         ; Error message if user enters same destination for pickup and dropoff
    mov ah , 09h
   lea dx , invalid_destination
   int 21h
   jmp get_dropoff

destination:
    call clear_screen           ; Added
    call set_cursor_0_0         ; Added

    mov ah , 09h
   lea dx , pickupchosen
   int 21h

   mov dl , pickupChoice
   add dl , 30h
   mov ah , 02h
   int 21h

   mov ah , 09h
   lea dx , dropoffchosen
   int 21h

   mov dl , dropoffChoice
   add dl , 30h
   mov ah , 02h
   int 21h

; Prompt for the quantity of tickets

   mov al , 0          ; Clear the al register just in case

get_ticketquantity:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , quantityPrompt
    int 21h

; Read user input for quantity

    mov ah , 01h
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h            ; Change to integer
 
; Check if the quantity is valid (between 1 and 9)

    cmp al , 1
    jl invalidquantity
    cmp al , 9
    jg invalidquantity

    mov ticketQuantity, al      ; Protect the value
    jmp extrafeatures

    invalidquantity:

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx, invalid_quantity    ; Display error message for invalid quantity
    int 21h

    jmp get_ticketquantity      ; Repeat the loop to get a valid quantity

extrafeatures:
    call clear_screen           ; Added
    call set_cursor_0_0         ; Added
    
extrafeaturesadded:             ; Added
    
;Code to display any extra features the user may input
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , features
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , snacks
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , beverages
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , entertainment
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , wifi
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuresprompt
    int 21h

    mov ah , 01h
    int 21h
    sub al , 30h                    ; Protect the input

    cmp al , 0
    je displayfeatures              ; Jump to displayfeatures if user enters 0
    cmp al , 1
    je addsnacks
    cmp al , 2
    je addbeverages
    cmp al , 3
    je addentertainment
    cmp al , 4
    je addwifi

    jmp invalidfeature

    addsnacks:
    or featuresChoice, 1            ; If user chooses snacks, the corresponding bit is set (bit 1)
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
     call set_cursor_0_0            ; Added 
   ; int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeaturesadded

    addbeverages:
    or featuresChoice, 2            ; If user chooses beverages, the corresponding bit is set (bit 2)
    call clear_screen                       ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
     call set_cursor_0_0            ; Added 
    ;int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeaturesadded

    addentertainment:
    or featuresChoice, 4            ; If user chooses entertainment, the corresponding bit is set (bit 3)
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
     call set_cursor_0_0            ; Added 
    ;int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeaturesadded

    addwifi:
    or featuresChoice, 8            ; If user chooses wifi, the corresponding bit is set (bit 4)
    call clear_screen                       ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
     call set_cursor_0_0            ; Added 
    ;int 10h
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , featuremessage
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeaturesadded

    invalidfeature:
    cmp al , 1
    jne validfeature                ; If true , jump to valid feature option that 
                                    ; repeats without showing invalid feature message
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and let user to choose anymore extra features
    ;int 10h

    mov ah , 09h                    ; If it didn't jump , this error message will appear
    lea dx , invalid_feature
    int 21h
    jmp extrafeaturesadded

    validfeature:                   ; If the jump occured it will just loop back as normal
    jmp extrafeaturesadded

displayfeatures:
    jmp finaldisplay                ; Jump to final display

finaldisplay:
    call clear_screen                   ; Clear screen and summarize the user order
     call set_cursor_0_0            ; Added     
  ;  int 10h 
        
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , pickupchosen
    int 21h

    mov dl , pickupChoice
    add dl , 30h
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , dropoffchosen
    int 21h

    mov dl , dropoffChoice
    add dl , 30h
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h

    mov ah  , 09h
    lea dx , quantityPrompt
    int 21h

    mov dl , ticketQuantity
    add dl , 30h
    mov ah , 02h
    int 21h

    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , chosenfeatures
    int 21h

    ; Check snacks
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 1    ; Check the least significant bit (snacks)
    cmp al , 1
    je snacks_chosen
    jmp beverages_check

snacks_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , snacks
    int 21h
    jmp beverages_check

beverages_check:
    ; Check beverages (bit 1)
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 2    ; Check bit 1 (beverages)
    cmp al , 2
    je beverages_chosen
    jmp entertainment_check

beverages_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , beverages
    int 21h
    jmp entertainment_check

entertainment_check:
    ; Check entertainment (bit 2)
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 4    ; Check bit 2 (entertainment)
    cmp al , 4
    je entertainment_chosen
    jmp wifi_check

entertainment_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , entertainment
    int 21h
    jmp wifi_check

wifi_check:
    ; Check WiFi (bit 3)
    mov ah , 0
    mov al , featuresChoice
    and al , 8    ; Check bit 3 (WiFi)
    cmp al , 8
    je wifi_chosen
    jmp final

wifi_chosen:
    mov ah , 09h
    lea dx , wifi
    int 21h
    jmp final

final:
    mov ah,8                    ; w8 4 key to read messages
    int 21h
    
    mov ax,0003h                ; Added
    int 10h                     ; Added 
   
   mov ax , 4c00h
   int 21h


    main    endp
    
    clear_screen:
        mov ax,0b800h
        mov es,ax           ; es = b800h
        mov ax,1F00h        ; ah = character's attribute, al = character
                            ; white on blue
        mov di,0            ; di = 0    
        cld             
        mov cx,25*80
        rep stosw           ; copy from ax to es:di 
        ret
        
    set_cursor_0_0:
        mov ah,02h
        mov dx,0
        int 10h

        ret
end main
```

Comment: Well, here is Your full code. I added, removed or changed few things. No more big letters, random characters and colors or printing text from middle of the screen.